# Multiuser Configuration in Clould 9 ide

Tags: cloud9-ide

I was Configured Clould 9 ide with MyUbuntu os locally in my system, Now i need to create multiple users on this Clould 9 Ide Locally and i would like to give different workspace for each user.

Thanks,
Pradeep.